# Mongodb Registration Form on php

Tags: php, mongodb

can you please tell me whats wrong with this code! i am trying to pass through post which i get error!

```
<?php
include_once("config.php");
if(loggedIn()):
    header('Location: members.php');
endif; 
if(isset($_POST["submit"])):
    if(!($_POST["password"] == $_POST["password2"])):
        echo "<p>Your passwords did not match</p>";
        exit;
    endif;
    $query = $collection->findOne(array("login" => $_POST["login"]));
    if(empty($query)):
        newUser($_POST["login"], $_POST["password"]);
        cleanMemberSession($_POST["login"], $_POST["password"]);
        header("Location: members.php");
        else:
        echo '<p>Username already exists, please choose another username.</p>';
    endif;
endif;
?>
```

Comment: That code has many errors in it. You should probably address those (which would likely be easier if it all weren't one line).`if(isset($_POSTif(` will never work.

Comment: You really expect us to read your code? It isn't formatted or anything...

Comment: can i email my code to one of you its because i am using aptana studio php!

Comment: Just format your code correctly in the question then I will read it

Comment: Tear down and start over with some basic php tutorials. That code is all kinds of broken.

Comment: ok check it now i am trying build registration form! can i do php and html on same page!

Comment: i get error on my server when i open it! from $qury it comes up on the server!

Comment: i am still waiting my html code probs wrong!

Comment: <form action="<?=$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>" method="POST">
<tr>
<td align='center'>User Name:</td><td><input type="text" name-"login" value="<?php print isset($_POST["login"]) ? $_POST["login"] : "" ; ?>"/></td>
</tr><tr>
<td align='center'>Password:</td>
<td><input type="password" name="password"/></td> 
<tr>
<td align='center'>Confirm Password:</td>
<input type="password" name="password2"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign up"/></td>
 </form>

Comment: @GunnerAziz i duno my html code is ok aswell its not

Comment: @Sammaye check it now

Comment: where is your collection defined?

Comment: i made functions php page plus mongodb php page!